# Does a web application avoid becoming a "derivative work" if it loads in an unmodified GPL-2 javascript library?

Tags: gpl, derivative-works, gpl-2

Say I have a web page:

```
...
<!-- A custom javascript library -->
<script src="myCustomScript.js"></script>

<!-- A GPL2 javascript library -->
<script src="GPLv2Library.js"></script>

<!-- A MIT licensed javascript library -->
<script src="MITLibrary.js"></script>

<script>

//other custom javascript

</script>

<body>
...
```

Does the presence of the GPL2 library affect the licence options for the custom scripts (assuming the GPL2 licence text is included in the GPL2 library source and that the source code has not been modified), or the MIT licensed library?

Does the whole webpage/application escape being classified as a "derivative work"? If not, are there any ways to avoid it?

Comment: There is one very simple way to avoid it becoming a derivative of a library: don't use it.

Comment: I am sure this question is a duplicate. And I am sure that the answer is yes. If you don't modify the GPL code, then you are only using it. This disables about 90% of the license (until it is modified, then the rest applies to who ever modifies it). You do still have to provide the library in source form (preferred form for editing: not minified, or obfuscated. You can minify but have to also provide access to preferred form, add a footnote about its use, and the download link. )

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor You also have to license the entire derivative work as GPL, if this counts as a derivative work. That's kinda important.

Comment: @user253751 the question is "is this a derivative work?"

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor because of the way I phrased the question, it's "is this **not** a derivative work" -> is that what you answered yes to?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Well in my opinion, the whole web application counts as a work, and it's certainly derived from its parts, but I'm not a lawyer.